# How to modify an HTML element in Elm after the page is rendered?

Tags: html, elm

I'm writing a Single-Page Application in Elm. After the page is rendered, I need to modify some element's properties by some event.

For example, let's say I have a `div` with a set of classes assigned to it, and now I want to `toggle` its `classList` when a button on the page is pressed. How can I do that using just native Elm constructions?

I know that such goal can be achieved by using 'old good' JavaScript plus Elm ports, but is there a way for doing that by using just Elm with no 'external' JavaScript and Elm ports?

**updated after some comments**

1. all the page is rendered and constructed by Elm, no 'external' JavaScript code;
2. I would like to update just the HTML element, without re-rendering all the page.

Comment: Is the div you want to modify generated by Elm code or does it exist outside of the Elm mount point?

Comment: @ChadGilbert the div is generated by Elm (like the rest of the page), no JavaScript code outside of the application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can construct your `view` function return
div with appropriate classes depending on your model.

Following example, div gets class "black" when model
is 1.  No classes attached to the div otherwise.
And click event updates the model.

```elm
-- UPDATE
type Msg
  = ToggleColor

update : Msg -> Model -> (Model, Cmd Msg)
update msg model =
  case msg of
    ToggleColor -> (if model == 0 then 1 else 0, Cmd.none)

-- VIEW
view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
  let
    classAttributes = classList [("black", model == 1)]
  in div [ classAttributes, onClick ToggleColor ] [ text "test" ]
```

Comment: As far as I understand (I'm might be mistaken, sorry), in this case we need to re-render the whole page, not just the HTML element, - is that correct? If so, is there a way to update just the element and not re-rendering the whole page? Thanks!

Comment: No, Elm will only update the necessary parts of the page. See http://elm-lang.org/blog/blazing-fast-html

Comment: which makes it unable to use with other frameworks doing it's own dom transformations like ionic